# How do I Instantiate Objects In Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a top down game in Unity, how do I instantiate objects based on the players current position from the top of the camera view in Unity?

So far I have tried:

```
Instantiate(prefab, player.transform.position * 2 * Space.World)
```

but this didn't work. This just spawned objects from the center of the camera.

Comment: What does `Instantiate(prefab, player.transform.position)` do?

Comment: where is "player.transform.position" 0,0,0 by any chance?

Comment: The player is constantly moving, so the position is always being updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Space`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Space.html) is simply an enum and has nothing to do with what you are trying! (Its purpose is to define the relative transform space for e.g. [`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) or [`Transform.Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html))

in that enum afaik

- `Space.World` simply has the int value `0`
- `Space.Self` has the int value `1`

so what you actually do is

```
Instantiate(prefab, player.transform.position * 2 * 0);
```

which equals

```
Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero);
```

which means the object is instantiated at World position `0,0,0`.

Also using

```
Instantiate(prefab, player.transform.position * 2);
```

looks a bit strange. Are you sure you want to duplicate the actual `position` of the `player`? This would mean the spawned object is always on a line with the player and the World `0,0,0` and always double as far from the center as the player.

---

To me it sounds more like you rather want to spawn something **in front** of the player ... depending on the player's **view direction** (in topdown games usually `player.transform.up` or `player.transform.right`) so I guess what you are trying to do instead is something like

```
Instantiate(prefab, player.transform.position + player.transform.forward * 2);
```

which would instead spawn the object `2` Unity units in front of the player object

---

After your comment it sounds like instead you want to spawn the object at the player position on the `X-axis` but "over it" on the `Y-axis` so

```
Instantiate(prefab, player.transform.position + Vector3.Up * 2);
```

maybe you'll have to tweak the `2` depending how your player can move and how far it has to be to be "off screen". Alternatively you could also use a bit more complex using [`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

```
// get players position
var playerPos = player.transform.position;

// get camera's position
var cameraPos = Camera.main.transform.position;

// get difference on Z-axis
var cameraDistance = cameraPos.z - playerPos.z;

// Get the world 3d point for the upper camera border
// don't care about the X value
// and as distance we use the z-distance to the player
var cameraTopPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, Camera.main.pixelHeight, cameraDistance);

// use the players X-axis position
cameraTopPoint.x = player.transform.x;

// to spawn it exactly on the Screen border above the player
Instantiate(prefab, cameraTopPoint);

// or to spawn it a bit higher
Instantiate(prefab, cameraTopPoint + Vector3.Up * 1);
```

---

**Update**

you said you want the prefab to be spawned on the "opposide" of the player position on the X axis.

If your Camera is static on world x=0 than this is actually quite simple:

```
cameraTopPoint.x = -player.transform.x;
```

If your camera is moving or not on x=0 than we have to calculate it already on the screen position level:

```
// get players position
var playerPos = player.transform.position;

// additionally convert the player position to screen space
var playerScreenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(playerPos);

var centerX = Camera.main.pixelWidth / 2.0f;

// get the difference between camera an player X (in screen space)
var differenceX = Mathf.Abs(playerScreenPos.x - centerX);

// here calculate the opposide side
var targetX = centerX + differenceX * (playerScreenPos.x < centerX ? 1 : -1);
// or alternatively if you want e.g. that the prefab always
// spawn with a bit of distance to the player even though he is very close
// to the center of the screen you could do something like
//var targetX = centerX + centerX / 2 * (playerScreenPos.x < centerX ? 1 : -1);

// Get the world 3d point for the upper camera border
// with the calculated X value
// and as distance we use the z-distance to the player
var cameraTopPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(targetX, Camera.main.pixelHeight, playerScreenPos.z);

// to spawn it exactly on the Screen border above the player
Instantiate(prefab, cameraTopPoint);

// or to spawn it a bit higher
Instantiate(prefab, cameraTopPoint + Vector3.Up * 1);
```

---

**Other Update**

Ok so you want the prefab always spawn next to the player in a certain distance. The side depends on which side of the screen the player is so you could actually use the first approach again but just add the desired distance:

```
// Adjust this is the Inspector (in Unity units)
public float spawnDistanceToPlayer;

...

// get players position
var playerPos = player.transform.position;

// additionally convert the player position to screen space
var playerScreenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(playerPos);

var centerX = Camera.main.pixelWidth / 2.0f;

// Get the world 3d point for the upper camera border
// with the calculated X value
// and as distance we use the z-distance to the player
var cameraTopPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(playerScreenPos.x, Camera.main.pixelHeight, playerScreenPos.z);

// now add or reduce spawnDistanceToPlayer 
// depending on which side of the screen he is
cameraTopPoint.x += spawnDistanceToPlayer * (playerScreenPos.x < centerX ? 1 : -1);

// OR if your camera sits static on X=0 anyway you also could compare
// the player position directly without calculating in screenspace:
cameraTopPoint.x += spawnDistanceToPlayer * (playerPos.x < 0 ? 1 : -1);

// to spawn it exactly on the Screen border above the player
Instantiate(prefab, cameraTopPoint);

// or to spawn it a bit higher
Instantiate(prefab, cameraTopPoint + Vector3.Up * 1);
```

---

*Typed on smartphone so might not be "copy-paste-able" ;)*

Comment: what does `exactly from the top of the camera view` mean?

Comment: oh ok I see ... Updated my answer at the bottom

Comment: You mean invert the `y` value?

Comment: please define `on the opposite side of the player`

Comment: So you want to invert the X value than. A bit more tricky but also possible of cause. Is your camera static and alway on world x=0 or does it move?

Comment: Ok I think now I got you ^^ see the latest update at the bottom